# What is the Math for this Pinescript output

Tags: pine-script

(Tradingview's Pinescript)
This might be math related, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

I have a script that calculates the MACD histogram for a 10,20,5 MACD and also evaluates the current price High/Low average. IF today's High/Low average > Yesterday's AND today's High/Low Average > Yesterday's, create a buy signal. A sell signal is produced from the opposite.
This is functioning properly.

What I'm trying to produce are two lines out to the side, with one signifying the threshold for when the opposite signal will be produced. The purpose is that someone can easily see how close things are to producing the opposite signal.

My code is currently

```
//@version=3
//Bollinger Bands with Buy and Sell Signaling
study(shorttitle="BB With Buy & Sell Signaling", title="BB With Buy & Sell Signaling", overlay=true)    

//Define MACD Variables
fast = 10, slow = 20
fastMACD = ema(hlc3, fast)
slowMACD = ema(hlc3, slow)
macd = fastMACD - slowMACD
signal = sma(macd, 5)
hist = macd - signal
currMacd = hist[0]
prevMacd = hist[1]
currPrice = hl2[0]
prevPrice = hl2[1]

buy = currPrice > prevPrice and currMacd > prevMacd
sell = currPrice < prevPrice and currMacd < prevMacd
neutral = (currPrice < prevPrice and currMacd > prevMacd) or (currPrice > prevPrice and currMacd < prevMacd)
//Plot Arrows

timetobuy = buy==1 and (sell[1]==1 or (neutral[1]==1 and sell[2]==1) or (neutral[1]==1 and neutral[2]==1 and sell[3]==1) or (neutral[1]==1 and neutral[2]==1 and neutral[3]==1 and sell[4]==1) or (neutral[1]==1 and neutral[2]==1 and neutral[3]==1 and neutral[4]==1 and sell[5]==1) or (neutral[1]==1 and neutral[2]==1 and neutral[3]==1 and neutral[4]==1 and neutral[5]==1 and sell[6]==1))



timetosell = sell==1 and (buy[1]==1 or (neutral[1]==1 and buy[2]==1) or (neutral[1]==1 and neutral[2]==1 and buy[3]==1) or (neutral[1]==1 and neutral[2]==1 and neutral[3]==1 and buy[4]==1) or (neutral[1]==1 and neutral[2]==1 and neutral[3]==1 and neutral[4]==1 and buy[5]==1) or (neutral[1]==1 and neutral[2]==1 and neutral[3]==1 and neutral[4]==1 and neutral[5]==1 and buy[6]==1))
plotshape(timetobuy, color=blue, location=location.belowbar, style=shape.arrowup)
plotshape(timetosell, color=red, location=location.abovebar, style=shape.arrowdown)
//plotshape(neutral, color=black, location=location.belowbar, style=shape.circle)

//THE CODE BELOW IS WHAT I NEED STACK EXCHANGE HELP WITH



linenow = currPrice + (currMacd - prevMacd)
limitline = prevPrice + (currMacd - prevMacd)

plot(linenow, color = blue, offset = 2, show_last = 1, linewidth = 2)
plot(limitline, color = red, offset = 2, show_last = 1, linewidth = 2)

plot(currPrice, color = blue, offset = 2, show_last = 1, linewidth = 2)
plot(prevPrice, color = red, offset = 2, show_last = 1, linewidth = 2)
plot(linenow, color = blue, offset = 3, show_last = 1, linewidth = 2)
plot(limitline, color = red, offset = 3, show_last = 1, linewidth = 2)
```

I've done a lot of trial and error. This most recent edition, I'm trying to produce the lines individually to see if they accurately show the results based on the arrows. Once I get this sorted out and working, I'll be combining them into a single pair of lines.

Right now, they are displaying, but I've got some math wrong somewhere I think. Sometimes they indicate correctly, other times they don't. They should be showing the current status, and the threshold where it will reverse.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of what you have and feel free to add your notes on it, of what you expect/want to see. TBH, I don't fully understand your question.